# Align drop down menu - left

Tags: html, css, menu

When I hover over a page name on my horizontal navigational menu the relative sub-pages float below.

At the moment these are showing centered, how can I align these so they align left (in line with the navigational menu title name).

You can see this by going to

```
http://79.170.44.145/sweetfe2.co.uk/
```

Hovering over "Business Services" see that menu that drop downs? I'd like that to align left so page links such as 'Practice Studios Oxford' will have both sentences floating left directly down below 'Business Services'.

Many thanks,

Sam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use 'text-align:left`to`.sub-menu` to align the text to left

```
.sub-menu{
  text-align:left;
  width: 176px;
}
```

add margin-left to align the sub menu with the main menu item

```
.menu > li > ul{
  margin-left:12px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not add to your CSS:

```
.sub-menu{
  text-align:left;
}
```

You may also want to add `padding-left:12px` to align the sub menu items 'better'.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean:

**text-align: left;**

in /wp-content/themes/designfolio-pro/style.css?ver=3.8.1

```
nav ul ul {
    border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
    display: none;
    float: left;
    left: -1px;
    list-style: none outside none;
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: left;
    top: 30px;
    width: 150px;
    z-index: 89;
}
```

Comment: I agree it was already there but not working - fix above worked!